# Python: get a circular subimage of an image

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a two-level array that represent an image. How can I get a circular subimage from this image at given `x` and `y` positions using radius `r`?

If I wanted a quadrilateral subimage I could use this:

```
image[x-(r/2),x+(r/2):y-(r/2),y+(r/2)]
```

By a circular subimage I mean a regular matrix with some elements set to 0 leaving a circular "non-zero" part.

Example matrix:

```
12 42 92 82 33 23 43 21 23 43 98 73
32 32 42 13 98 67 24 54 19 32 43 54
13 32 98 78 67 30 92 48 21 38 83 45
12 42 92 82 33 23 43 21 23 43 98 73
32 32 42 13 98 67 24 54 19 32 43 54
13 32 98 78 67 30 92 48 21 38 83 45
12 42 92 82 33 23 11 21 23 43 98 73
32 32 42 13 98 67 24 54 19 32 43 54
13 32 98 78 67 30 92 48 21 38 83 45
12 42 92 82 33 23 43 21 23 43 98 73
32 32 42 13 98 67 24 54 19 32 43 54
13 32 98 78 67 30 92 48 21 38 83 45
```

Let's say `x = 6`, `y = 5` and `r = 2` then this would be an acceptable result:

```
 0  0 24  0  0
 0 30 92 48  0
33 23 11 21 23
 0 67 24 54  0
 0  0 92  0  0
```

Comment: What do you mean by circular? Matrices are rectangular. Do you mean a rectangular matrix with some elements set to `0` leaving a circular "non-zero" part?

Comment: Precisely. I will add this to the question, thanks!